# My wifi speed varies and at times drops to nothing

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, lenovo

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on Lenovo Ideapad Flex 10 laptop.

I had an old wifi router that my computer worked fine with, but now I have bought a new Wi-Fi router today (and a different data plan with the same ISP) and now when I connect to the router I can browse the internet for about 3 minutes then the speed drops from 300-400 KB/s to around 1KB/s at most and stays that way for up to 1 minute or longer before it goes back to the usual 300-400 KB/s speed only to drop out again after a few minutes.

What bothers me most is that even if I use the old router the computer does the same as on the new one, but it was working fine before I connected to a new network.

I can verify there is nothing wrong with the router/ISP as I have tested the Wi-FI on 3 different devices, 2 Windows 10 laptops and an Android 5.5.2, and they have no problem connecting or keeping a stable speed.

I am using a "Wifly-City High-Power Long Range And High Sensitivity 980000N Wi-Fi booster/Range extender", but with or without it the computer has the same problem.

Output from running `sudo lshw -class network`

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 01
       serial: d0:53:49:88:c3:ec
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.8.0-58-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:d0400000-d047ffff memory:d0480000-d048ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlx00e04cd839a8
       serial: 00:e0:4c:d8:39:a8
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.8.0-58-generic firmware=0.29 ip=192.168.1.2 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `iwconfig; dmesg | grep queue`

Answer (score 0):

I have done some testing and had someone with more knowledge towards Linux than me have a look at the problem.

It seems there is a hardware issue with my Qualcomm wifi card unfortunately there isn't much of an option to fix it other than replacing the motherboard, because the card is integrated into the motherboard.

It seems the best option i have is buying a new laptop.